# Aure AAD - API or SDK for Sign out from all devices feature

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there an azure aad api that can be invoked to kill all refresh_tokens for a particular app?
So that after an hour, new tokens will not be issued and devices under the app-id will signout automatically.
Pls note the signout should delete refresh tokens for a particular appid, not all the tokens from the user.

Comment: You will have to use Publish subscribe method here. You can publish a message to a topic when you want refresh tokens to be invalidated. Each app instance can have its own temporary subscription(until its lifetime) and listen to the messages from that topic and then performs logout operation on all instances.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such an official API.

The only call which is exposed by Microsoft is revoke all refresh tokens issued to all applications for a user.

See [Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0).

AAD Graph API: `POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/me/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1`

You can post your idea on [Azure AD User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).